# Have the compiler throw an error if a const int does not have a unique value

Tags: c#, constants

I have a bunch of `public const int` variables defined in a C# class, and their values are initialized as well. Is there a way to have the compiler throw a compiler error if the value of each variable is not unique? I don't want my project to compile if there is a value collision between the variables.

Comment: That's not possible.  Public const is quite a bad idea in general.

Comment: Best you can do is check with reflection at runtime and throw an exception.

Comment: @Tim: That doesn't catch it at compile-time.

Comment: Would an enum make more sense?  Instead of manually defining each numerical value, just list out the enum values and it automatically numbers them.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create a custom [Fx Cop Rule](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/FxCop1.aspx) that will look at the `public const int` members in your class and check the values assigned to them. You can then add this rule to your Code Analysis Ruleset and set it to **Error** (rather than warn) on Failure.

Answer (score 2):

Cases in a switch statement must be unique, therefore you can use a `switch` statement with a case for each variable you want to ensure doesn't overlap the others.

```
static class ColorSwatches
{
    public const int Red = 0, Gray = 1, Blue = 2, Yellow = 3, Grey = 1;


    static ColorSwatches()
    {
        switch (0) {
            case Red:     break;
            case Gray:    break;
            case Blue:    break;
            case Yellow:  break;
            case Grey:    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does require that all the constants be listed a second time, in the `switch`.

(Sidebar: This also works in C++, where I've used it for compile-time assertion before `static_assert` was added.)

Comment: Thats an.... interesting approach to enforcing a compiler rule. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Define them in an enum. You can still specify values if you don't want them monotonically increasing from zero, but the compiler will barf if there are any repeated values.

Comment: Are you SURE the compiler won't allow repeated values?